# Pygame segmentation fault with import depending on position in code?

Tags: python, import, pygame, segmentation-fault

I know these segmentation fault questions are common, but I couldn't find answer and I am pulling my hair out as the code works without issue in some parts of the code, but not others or in some cases it works the first time then, the next day, it falls over.

Basically, I am importing spritesheets for a simply pygame game. With help, I wrote a small class which allows spritesheets to be imported and, through a few methods turns them into a list using the json file. That program is as follows:

```
import pygame
import json


pygame.init()

class Spritesheet:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
        self.data_addr = self.filename.replace('png', 'json')
        
        with open(self.data_addr, encoding = 'utf8') as f:
            self.data = json.load(f)
        f.close()
        
      
    def check_file(self):
        
          print(self.data)
    
    def get_sprite(self, x, y, w, h):
        sprite = pygame.Surface((w, h))
        sprite.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
        sprite.blit(self.sprite_sheet,(0, 0),(x, y, w, h))
        return sprite

    def parse(self, index):
        sprite = self.data['frames'][index]['frame']
        x, y, w, h = sprite["x"], sprite["y"], sprite["w"], sprite["h"]
        image = self.get_sprite(x, y, w, h)
        return image
                    
    def dict_len(self):
        length = len(self.data['frames'])
        return length
```

This has worked fine in the main code. I have a player class, an enemy class etc and, upon initiallising, this class is called to create a list of pngs for the graphics (that I can step through etc.) A pertinent cut of the player class is as follows:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, player_posx, health):
        super().__init__()
        
        #right facing sprites
        self.spritesr = Spritesheet('../graphics/player/players.png')
        self.player_spritesr = []
        for value in range(self.spritesr.dict_len()):
            self.player_spritesr.append(self.spritesr.parse(value))
            
        # left facing sprites
        self.spritesl = Spritesheet('../graphics/player/playersl.png')
        self.player_spritesl = []
        for value in range(self.spritesl.dict_len()):
            self.player_spritesl.append(self.spritesl.parse(value))
            
        #static sprites
        self.sprites_static = Spritesheet('../graphics/player/player_static.png')
        self.player_static = []
        for value in range(self.sprites_static.dict_len()):
            self.player_static.append(self.sprites_static.parse(value))
        
        self.image_index = 0
        self.image = self.player_spritesr[self.image_index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

In this class it works fine with the Spritesheets class. However, when I decided to create new file to import all the graphics in a separate file, I get the segmentation error. The code is simply:

```
from spritesheets import Spritesheet

test = Spritesheet('../graphics/player/playersl.png')
```

Calling exactly the same class with the same argument, but I get an error saying:
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
Python runtime state: initialized

I really don't understand at all, especially why it runs fine in one file but falls over everywhere else.

Comment: I do not know the pygame library at all, but noticing you have a `pygame.init()` right at the top level of a module I have a sneaky suspicion that it might be causing your issue. Even if its not the issue its an invitation for problems to do initialization work at import time in a module and usually this manifests itself with weird bugs where the order of imports matter...and if you think about it I think you will not find it hard to see why.

Comment: One reason to use a context manager (`with`) is so that you wouldn't need to call `f.close()` because it does that automatically when you exit it

Comment: I can't reproduce the segfault, could you provide the entire traceback and, perhaps, your entire codebase (for example, using GitHub), as well as what version of pygame you are using (or just send the entire console output, since it should include that too)

Answer (score 0):

The likely problem is that you are doing your import before you have called `pygame.init()`, so pygame has not been initialized.

Consider doing this in your second file:

```
from spritesheets import Spritesheet

def get_sprites():
    return [
        Spritesheet('../graphics/player/players.png'),
        Spritesheet('../graphics/player/playersl.png'),
        Spritesheet('../graphics/player/players_static.png')
    ]
```

Now you can put your `import` at the top, and call

```
sprites = xxx.get_sprites()
```

after you have initialized pygame.

Comment: They initialize `pygame` in the `spritesheet` file, also the part of traceback they sent states that the state of `pygame` is _initialized_.